# adding remarketing code directly to link (link generator)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, google-ads-api

I have a following use case for the Retargeting link generator:

1. Add one or more retargeting codes directly to your link. When somebody clicks he will be automatically added to remarketing/retargeting list.

I'm going to code a script in JS on my domain which will do such thing.
Which steps should I make ? Maybe there is a Wordpress plugin or any other open source script that I didn't find.

I want something similar to this -> https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211032966-Retargeting-on-your-links

Please give me any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :) - I've used Wordpress plugins:
- ACF Custom Fields
- ACF Code Field

then everything should be done on template page with $redirectURL and $scriptField :)